# Get random boolean in Java

Tags: java, random, boolean

Okay, I implemented this SO question to my code: [Return True or False Randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878015/return-true-or-false-randomly)

But, I have strange behavior: I need to run ten instances simultaneously, where every instance returns true or false just once per run. And surprisingly, no matter what I do, every time i get just `false`

Is there something to improve the method so I can have at least roughly 50% chance to get `true`?

---

To make it more understandable: I have my application builded to JAR file which is then run via batch command

```
 java -jar my-program.jar
 pause
```

Content of the program - to make it as simple as possible:

```
public class myProgram{

    public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
        return Math.random() < 0.5;
        // I tried another approaches here, still the same result
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandomBoolean());  
    }
}
```

If I open 10 command lines and run it, I get `false` as result every time...

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Why not using `Random r = new Random();
  r.nextBoolean();`

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I recommend using [`Random.nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean%28%29)

That being said, `Math.random() < 0.5` as you have used works too. Here's the behavior on my machine:

```
$ cat myProgram.java 
public class myProgram{

   public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
       return Math.random() < 0.5;
       //I tried another approaches here, still the same result
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(getRandomBoolean());  
   }
}

$ javac myProgram.java
$ java myProgram ; java myProgram; java myProgram; java myProgram
true
false
false
true
```

Needless to say, there are **no guarantees** for getting different values each time. In your case however, I suspect that

A) you're not working with the code you think you are, (like editing the wrong file)

B) you havn't compiled your different attempts when testing, or

C) you're working with some non-standard broken implementation.

Answer (score 50):

Have you tried looking at the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--)?

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed boolean value from this random number generator's sequence ... the values `true` and `false` are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

For example:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random random = new Random();
random.nextBoolean();
```

Answer (score 35):

You could also try `nextBoolean()`-Method
Here is an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextboolean.htm

Comment: Much more, I even tried the nextBoolean and got the same result. (10 false in row). Obviously the program is much more complicated than what I wrote, so either I am really lucky person, or really stupid programmer :)

Comment: @Pavel Janicek And after that 10 false in a row? or do you get allways falses? I once had the same problem with a c# project I wrote, there I did something wrong at the initialisation part. I also got allways the same results, each start. may you post your initialisation code too?!

Comment: Okay there can be the catch! I did not initialise the value properly :) At least upvote for this ... ;)

Answer (score 12):

**Java 8**: Use random generator isolated to the current thread: [ThreadLocalRandom nextBoolean()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextBoolean--)

> Like the global Random generator used by the Math class, a ThreadLocalRandom is initialized with an internally generated seed that may not otherwise be modified. When applicable, use of ThreadLocalRandom rather than shared Random objects in concurrent programs will typically encounter much less overhead and contention.

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, which has a method `nextBoolean`:

```
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate 10 random booleans. */
public final class MyProgram {

  public static final void main(String... args){

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      boolean randomBool = randomGenerator.nextBoolean();
      System.out.println("Generated : " + randomBool);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for an unbiased result:

```
Random random = new Random();
//For 50% chance of true
boolean chance50oftrue = (random.nextInt(2) == 0) ? true : false;
```

**Note:** random.nextInt(2) means that the number 2 is the bound. the counting starts at 0. So we have 2 possible numbers (0 and 1) and hence the probability is 50%!

If you want to give more probability to your result to be true (or false) you can adjust the above as following!

```
Random random = new Random();

//For 50% chance of true
boolean chance50oftrue = (random.nextInt(2) == 0) ? true : false;

//For 25% chance of true
boolean chance25oftrue = (random.nextInt(4) == 0) ? true : false;

//For 40% chance of true
boolean chance40oftrue = (random.nextInt(5) < 2) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to initialize a random number generator is to use the parameterless constructor, for example

```
Random generator = new Random();
```

However, in using this constructor you should recognize that algorithmic random number generators are not truly random, they are really algorithms that generate a fixed but random-looking sequence of numbers.

You can make it appear more 'random' by giving the Random constructor the 'seed' parameter, which you can dynamically built by for example using system time in milliseconds (which will always be different)

Comment: Erm, the parameterless constructor does exactly that (mostly, at least). You rarely have to set a seed directly unless you know what you're doing. Which almost never applies for this sort of questions. And it won't make the sequence look "more random". It's simply a different sequence (bound to the seed), then.

Answer (score 0):

you could get your clock() value and check if it is odd or even. I dont know if it is %50 of true

And you can custom-create your random function:

```
static double  s=System.nanoTime();//in the instantiating of main applet
public static double randoom()
{

s=(double)(((555555555* s+ 444444)%100000)/(double)100000);


    return s;
}
```

numbers 55555.. and 444.. are the big numbers to get a wide range function
please ignore that skype icon :D

Comment: you may not get the true cpu cycles but can get a low resolution clock cycles . then you have an error range, which you have random points every time you get a clock() value. Statistically must be %50 if error range is symmetrical

Comment: He isn't asking for a double generator, so the code snippet you posted is pretty irrelevant. Secondly, checking if current time is even is not a great idea for several reasons. System.nanoTime() has no guarantee to have precision on nanosecond level. Mine only has microsecond precision. Hence, it is always even --> always true. Secondly if the random function is to be called multiple times with short time in between, the generated random value will depend on previous values. If you use currentTimeMillis() and call the random generator 100 times / ms the generator will yield 100 trues in a row.

Comment: if it is always true, then it doesnt have a deviation.             bit=(boolean)s;  if you need randomness, you will need random error range. error which is unsuspected behaviour just like random things. Thats why i have given System.nanoTime() intentionally to get error range. But you are right about the slowness of System.nanoTime() that is why it is used as a "seed". then the randoom() is used as fast as computer can

Comment: My point was, altough it didn't fit within the word limit of my previous comment, that it is better to use Java's built in random functions rather than making some own ad hoc random implementation based on uninvestigated assumptions.

Comment: Just in case of he didnt like the libraries. Maybe his java version has some bug or damaged. I dont know. I only told what i know

Answer (score 0):

You can also make two random integers and verify if they are the same, this gives you more control over the probabilities.

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Declare a range to manage random probability.
In this example, there is a 50% chance of being true.

```
int range = 2;
```

Generate 2 random integers.

```
int a = rand.nextInt(range);
int b = rand.nextInt(range);
```

Then simply compare return the value.

```
return a == b;
```

I also have a class you can use.
[RandomRange.java](https://github.com/Fethore/Sample-Code/blob/master/RandomRange.java)

Answer (score 0):

Words in a text are always a source of randomness. Given a certain word, nothing can be inferred about the next word. For each word, we can take the ASCII codes of its letters, add those codes to form a number. The parity of this number is a good candidate for a random boolean.

Possible drawbacks:

1. this strategy is based upon using a text file as a source for the words. At some point, 
   the end of the file will be reached. However, you can estimate how many times you are expected to call the randomBoolean()
   function from your app. If you will need to call it about 1 million times, then a text file with 1 million words will be enough. 
   As a correction, you can use a stream of data from a live source like an online newspaper.
2. using some statistical analysis of the common phrases and idioms in a language, one can estimate the next word in a phrase, 
   given the first words of the phrase, with some degree of accuracy. But statistically, these cases are rare, when we can accuratelly 
   predict the next word. So, in most cases, the next word is independent on the previous words.

   package p01;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;

   public class Main {

   ```
   String words[];
   int currentIndex=0;

   public static String readFileAsString()throws Exception 
     { 
       String data = ""; 
       File file = new File("the_comedy_of_errors");
       //System.out.println(file.exists());
       data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getName()))); 
       return data; 
     } 

   public void init() throws Exception
   {
       String data = readFileAsString(); 
       words = data.split("\\t| |,|\\.|'|\\r|\\n|:");
   }

   public String getNextWord() throws Exception
   {
       if(currentIndex>words.length-1)
           throw new Exception("out of words; reached end of file");

       String currentWord = words[currentIndex];
       currentIndex++;

       while(currentWord.isEmpty())
       {
           currentWord = words[currentIndex];
           currentIndex++;
       }

       return currentWord;
   }

   public boolean getNextRandom() throws Exception
   {
       String nextWord = getNextWord();
       int asciiSum = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < nextWord.length(); i++){
           char c = nextWord.charAt(i);        
           asciiSum = asciiSum + (int) c;
       }

       System.out.println(nextWord+"-"+asciiSum);

       return (asciiSum%2==1) ;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
       Main m = new Main();
       m.init();
       while(true)
       {
           System.out.println(m.getNextRandom());
           Thread.sleep(100);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

In Eclipse, in the root of my project, there is a file called 'the_comedy_of_errors' (no extension) - created with  File> New > File , where I pasted some content from here: http://shakespeare.mit.edu/comedy_errors/comedy_errors.1.1.html

Answer (score 0):

## For a flexible boolean randomizer:

```
public static rbin(bias){
    bias = bias || 50;
    return(Math.random() * 100 <= bias);
    /*The bias argument is optional but will allow you to put some weight
      on the TRUE side. The higher the bias number, the more likely it is
      true.*/
}
```

Make sure to use numbers `0` - `100` or you might lower the bias and get more common `false` values.

###### PS: I do not know anything about Java other than it has a few features in common with JavaScript. I used my JavaScript knowledge plus my inferring power to construct this code. Expect my answer to not be functional. Y'all can edit this answer to fix any issues I am not aware of.

Comment: You need to declare var types, or use `var` to let compiler infer.