# How to randomly select one from two integers?

Tags: java, select, random, int

So lets say I want to randomly choose from the set of two numbers `1` and `3`.

How do I go about doing that? Do I just assign `int a` to `1`, `int b` to `3`, and then do randomly select from `a` and `b`?

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055287/select-a-random-value-from-an-array#9055314

Comment: Or that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878015/return-true-or-false-randomly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 6):

If there are only two numbers to choose from then you can use the value of a `boolean`, because it returns either `true` or `false`.

One-liner solution assuming that `int a = 1` and `int b = 3`:

```
int randomOfTwoInts = new Random().nextBoolean() ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific list of numbers then put them in list structure (an array works well). Then you have the easier task of looking for a random index in the range from 0 to last array index. This post lists strategies for doing that:[How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)